# How can I implement animated particles in JS?

Tags: javascript

The look I'm aiming for is not an animated gif that has a directional vector but either propogates interestingly or creates additional motion or visual detail.

Comment: You should try something yourself and then come back with a more specific question.

Comment: How does this contribute in any way?  This is a legitimate question and you could give a legitimate response.

Comment: @JohnHaugeland The problem is that the OP's question is very vague / open ended, and doesn't show any research or effort on his/her own part. Your answer is good, and I'm happy to see someone took on the task of answering it as you did, but even you were only able to answer in a general way. As it says in the stackoverflow FAQ, the best questions should be "reasonably scoped", not asking for an entire book on the subject.

Comment: A healthy community does not turn outsiders away merely for scorn over their ability to ask deep questions.  If we wanted that kind of neckbeardry, we'd go to IRC.  Now if you'll excuse me, I've just exposed myself as a Redditor by making a Go Back to Digg style comment, which in true form I need to mark as a No True Scotsman.  (PS: have a sense of humor and some charity.  Not everyone knows where to start.)

Comment: I mean the kid started with "how do I make a Win8 game in JS" and they shut his question down, so he said "how do I make animated particles" and he's getting voted through the floor.  Give him a break, huh?

Comment: I apologize - I'm no graphic designer and I wanted to add a little bit of flair to some particles. I consider transparency gradients, distortion effects visually interesting, but am not sure what else is available to me considering the platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So there's three pieces to this.

1) How do I show the particles

2) How do I animate them

3) How do I make them "interesting"

Right, so.

1 is pretty easy.  There are, as always, a billion approaches.  The easiest, if you're willing to stick to a modern browser and if you're happy with modest quality results - which you should be, in a stepping stone - is to just make a PNG of one particle, then to create an `<img src="that">`, put it at the origin point (let's say the center for now,) and animate it outwards.  Maybe fade it in or whatever.

2 is maybe pretty easy.  Depends on a lot of choices.  Can you stick to just a modern browser?  If you're making an iPhone or Win8 game, you know exactly what browser you're targetting, and the answer is yes.  If it's the web, the answer is no.  If you know it's a modern browser, use CSS3 transitions, and the work is trivial.  If you don't, use jQuery or Scriptaculous or something, and it's merely very easy, instead.

3 ... eh, I mean, interesting is a hard to define word.  Start with emitting them in waves or a spiral.  Then try random.  Then try semi-random - you emit them in well defined ranges so you get random-looking but you get good coverage.  Look at bullet hell games for inspiration.

Comment: Is there anything I can do do filter effects over an existing particle to create a warp effect around each particle?

Comment: Yeah.  You could do it in `<canvas>` and handle it yourself, or you could fake it pretty convincingly with gradients in SVG.  You could do it legit in WebGL, but that locks you out of IE.  There are ways to fake it pretty not-awfully with transparent PNGs.  Etc etc.

But don't get ahead of yourself.  Start with "works."  Get pretty later.